# How do I find the order of elements in $\mathbb{C}^*$ (the multiplicative complex group)?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

I know the formula to find the order of an element in the form $m^k$ in a group with order $n$ is  $n/\gcd(k,n)$. However I don't know how to apply that formula when it comes to complex elements.

For example, if they ask me to find the order of   $e^{2\pi i \frac{8}{12}}$ in   $\mathbb{C}^*$, how would I proceed? How would I be able to find the generators? Also, I thought  $\mathbb{C}^*$ was a cyclic group of order infinite, so how can an element have a finite order?

Solution :
[image]

Comment: To what power do you raise the element to get the identity?  There can be elements of finite order in groups with infinite order; the identity element is one of those

Comment: i tried doing that but it have me a rational number. $(e^{2\pi i \frac{8}{12}})^n$ = $e^{2\pi i }$ and it gave me n = 4/6

Comment: $\left(\exp(2\pi i\frac23)\right)^3=1$

Comment: Note: $\Bbb C^*$ is not cyclic.

Comment: I just dont understand why my teacher said since its a reduced fraction the order is 3

Comment: 1) Your formula for order of $m^k$ is wrong, e.g., if $m$ is the identity, then the order of $m^k$ is one. 2) You don't say what "it" was that gave you $n=4/6$, but whatever it was, throw it out. $n=4/6$ does not work in that equation. 3) Draw the complex plane, sketch the group ${\bf C}^*$, locate the point $e^{2\pi i(8/12)}$, and think about the geometric effect of raising an element of ${\bf C}^*$ to a power.

Comment: The roots of unity are a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$.  Indeed, they are precisely the elements of $\mathbb{C}^*$ with a finite order!

Comment: Your teacher's argument in the solution was that because $2/3$ is a reduced fraction, the denominator must indicate what the order of the element is.  If $\omega = e^{2i\pi\cdot \frac{p}{q}}$ with $p/q$ reduced, then $\omega^q = 1$, and for any positive $n < q$, $\omega^n \ne 1$ since $2i\pi \cdot \frac{np}{q}$ is not of the form $2ki\pi$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArbitraryRenaissance thanks that made sense

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our question is, given an element $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$, what is the lowest *natural number* $n$ satisfying $z^n=1$?

Since we require that $z^n=1$, it only makes sense that $z$ is a root of unity; i.e. $z=e^{q2\pi i}$ for some $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. However, if $q=\frac{a}{b}$, we can't say that the order of $z$ is $\frac{b}{a}$ unless $\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer (that contradicts the definition of "order"). Thus, if $\frac{a}{b}$ is a reduced fraction, then the order must be $b$, to allow $z^b=(e^{\frac{a}{b}2\pi i})^b=e^{a2\pi i} = 1$.